# Free module of infinite rank.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbf{F}$ be a free module of infinity rank $\alpha$ over a ring $\mathbf{R}$ that has the invariant dimension property. For each cardinal $\beta$ such that $0\le$$\beta$$\le$$\alpha$, $\mathbf{F}$ has infinity many proper free submodules of rank $\beta$.
This is an exercise from GTM73 (Hungerford's Algebra), IV.2.11. I don't know to prove this and can't find a certain module which satisfies these conditions. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $X\subset F$ be a basis for $F$. For every positive integer $i$, let $F_i$ denote the set $F$ without it's $i$-th element. Since $\alpha$ is infinite, $F_i$ cardinality is also $\alpha$. Now, let $G_i$ denote the first $\beta$ elements $F_i$. Then each $G_i \neq G_j$ if $i\neq j$ and also, $RG_i$ is a free proper submodule of rank $\beta$.